# search for multiple keywords with php and mysql (where X like)

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have a code that dynamically search for data in the database using ajax but I can search for only 1 keyword in a time.  I would like to modify it so I can search for multiple keywords.  Now, if I type 2 keywords separated by a space and in the database, the data is not separated by a space, there will be no result.
If in the database the data is:

> 'playstation3' or 'play cool station3'

and I search for:

> play station

there would be no results.  I would like to know if it possible to modify my code so I can search 2 or more keywords or words separated by a space or another word or a DOT or  an underscore or a (-) or a (+) or a (%) or  (anything else lol).

I know that I should use pdo or mysqli but i'm using this for testing only!

```
$queried = $_POST['query'];



$search = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM links WHERE name LIKE '%$queried%'");
while($searche = mysql_fetch_array($search)){
    echo "".$searche['link']."</br>".$searche['name']."</br>".$searche['size']."</br>".$searche['category']."<hr></br></br>";

    }
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To dynamically search all keywords, you can use the explode function to seperate all keywords;

```
$queried = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['query']); // always escape

$keys = explode(" ",$queried);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM links WHERE name LIKE '%$queried%' ";

foreach($keys as $k){
    $sql .= " OR name LIKE '%$k%' ";
}

$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

**Note 1:** Always escape user input before using it in your query.

**Note 2:** mysql_* functions are deprecated, use Mysqli or PDO as an alternative

**Update 2018 - Note 3:** Don't forget to check the length of the `$queried` variable and set a limit. Otherwise the user can input a vary large string and crash your database.

Comment: How can this be converted to a prepared statement? Count the number of placeholders and add them dynamically-however that works?

Comment: @BillWhickomb you can use `count($keys)` to know how many parameters there are.

Comment: Do not forget to secure your query

Comment: @AmirhosseinTarmast that's what the very first line does. See a more [robust version here](https://idiallo.com/blog/php-mysql-search-algorithm)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `mysql_*` functions even for testing anymore. They are no easier than `mysqli`, just in case you think easy to test here then move.

However, you could split your input on a `,` and try this

```
<?php

$queried="abc,test, testing";
$values=explode(',',$queried);


$sql="SELECT * FROM links WHERE";
$i=0;

foreach($values as $v)
{
    $v=trim($v);
    if($i==0)
    {
        $sql.=" name LIKE '%$v%'";
    }
    else
    {
        $sql.=" OR name LIKE '%$v%'";
    }

    $i++;
}

$search = mysql_query($sql);
while($searche = mysql_fetch_array($search))
{
    echo "".$searche['link']."</br>".$searche['name']."</br>".$searche['size']."</br>".$searche['category']."<hr></br></br>";

}    
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works.  I think that I can automatically replace spaces by %20 and then automatically get the different words.  Thank you! it really helpful

Comment: Glad it helps. The `trim` function in here will automatically remove extra spaces from either the start or end of your keywords so you dont have to manually replace spaces

Answer (score 2):

This is a **MySQL PDO** version of @Hanky Panky's answer

```
 $queried="abc,test, testing";
 $values=explode(',',$queried);
 $sql="SELECT * FROM citations_new WHERE";
 $i=0;
        foreach($values as $v){
            $v=trim($v);
            if($i==0) {
                $sql.=" name LIKE '%$v%'";
            }
           else {
               $sql.=" OR name LIKE '%$v%'";
           }
           $i++;
         }

$sth = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
$rows = $sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

while($row = $sth->fetch()){
    //enter code here   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an OR clause.

E.g.

```
SELECT * FROM links WHERE name LIKE '%$keyword1%' OR name LIKE '%$keyword2%'
```

But I *strongly* recommend you using a parametrized query or other safe library to avoid [Sql Injection Attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: You are right, Thank you !  But I don't have 2 forms, I have 1 form and when I search, it not accurate.  Here is an example of what i'm looking for ---> http://mega-search.me/  When you type, you can put more than one keywords separated by a space and the query will find a result.