# Search for more than one keyword

Tags: php

I have this little php search script to help me search through my users table.

**Example:**

- If I search for "John", I get results
- If I search for "John Doe" (two words with a space) I get no results.
  Even if the users name is John Doe.

I was wondering if there is something in this script I could change to help me search for multiple key words.

**Here is the Search code:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['keywords'])){
    $keywords = escape($_GET['keywords']);

    $search = DB::getInstance()->query("
    SELECT `id`,`username`,`first_name`,`last_name`,`unit`,`email`,`rent_own`,`city`,`zip`,`phone`,`joined`,`group_id` FROM `users` WHERE 
    `username`    LIKE '%{$keywords}%' OR
    `first_name`  LIKE '%{$keywords}%' OR
    `last_name`   LIKE '%{$keywords}%' OR
    `unit`        LIKE '%{$keywords}%' OR
    `email`       LIKE '%{$keywords}%' OR
    `rent_own`    LIKE '%{$keywords}%' OR
    `city`        LIKE '%{$keywords}%' OR
    `zip`         LIKE '%{$keywords}%' OR
    `phone`       LIKE '%{$keywords}%' OR
    `joined`       LIKE '%{$keywords}%' OR
    `group_id`    LIKE '%{$keywords}%'  
    ");                



?>
```

Any thought or solutions are welcome and appreciated.

Comment: My first thought is that you're passing `John Doe` as a query string parameter which includes the space as `%20` in between the two words. Can you confirm that `$keywords` actually is `John Doe` when you intend it to be?

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure you are right about the space being `%20`. Is there a way I can fix that?

Comment: make sure $keywords = escape($_GET['keywords']); is doing what you THINK it'll do.

Comment: Explode your keywords and search in each database table row for each keyword, so you should get all possible data returned.

Comment: I have no idea about requirements. But it seems fulltext search can be useful here.

Comment: `echo` `$keywords` in standard SQL format and find out if the space is there.

Comment: another good answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15538479/search-for-multiple-keywords-with-php-and-mysql-where-x-like)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're searching by the full name you'll need to add a condition for it

```
CONCAT(`first_name`,' ',`last_name`) LIKE '%{$keywords}%' OR
```

Comment: the OP is asking about `username` not `first_name` & `last_name`.

Comment: @echo edit your question and mention about `first_name` and `last_name` instead of `user name`.

Comment: @FuzzyTree Also one more question. If I wanted to search for users in different user groups such as Admin moderator ...etc how could I do that if my `group_id` is numeric. Example: Admin =1 , moderator =2
If I search Admin I get no results.

Comment: @echo if you want to show admins when searching for that keyword, you'd have to join on `group_id` and add an or condition for the admin column

Comment: @FuzzyTree something like this:

 ` <?php 
if ($s->group_id == 1){
 echo 'admin';
}
elseif ($s->group_id == 2){
 echo 'moderater';
}
elseif ($s->group_id == 3){
 echo 'owner';
}
?>`

Answer (score 3):

When doing a search function of your site. Match and Against is better than Like sql statement. The field must be set to FullText match the term on the field:

```
SELECT `id`,`username`,`first_name`,`last_name`,`unit`,`email`,`rent_own`,`city`,`zip`,`phone`,`joined`,`group_id` FROM `users` WHERE MATCH(`id`,`username`,`first_name`,`last_name`,`unit`,`email`,`rent_own`,`city`,`zip`,`phone`,`joined`,`group_id`) AGAINST('keywords')
```

You can also use the IN BOOLEAN MODE to allow operators in the sql statement.
eg. ... `MATCH(`first_name`,`last_name`) AGAINST('-John +Doe' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` ...
(-) minus sign that means nothing should match 'John'
(+) the word must be present in the match.

There are many other operators to be used. Refer to [this page for more operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html) and explanation