# search for multiple keywords with php and mysql (where X like) set Limit

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to know how one can set limits to the queries suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15538479/search-for-multiple-keywords-with-php-and-mysql-where-x-like) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13214712/like-query-using-multiple-keywords-from-search-field-using-pdo-prepared-statemen)

For example where can i set a Limit to the solution suggested by @Ibu?

```
$queried = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['query']); // always escape

$keys = explode(" ",$queried);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM links WHERE name LIKE '%$queried%' ";

foreach($keys as $k){
    $sql .= " OR name LIKE '%$k%' ";
}

$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

I have tried setting it on the second `$sql` variable like this:

```
$sql .= " OR name LIKE '%$k%' LIMIT 0, 20 ";
```

However, this returns no results. Thank you in advance for your input.

Comment: Please stop using **mysql_** extension. It has been removed completely in PHP 7. Please use **mysqli_** or **PDO** libraries instead. Your code is open to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/2469308) related attacks. Please learn to use [Prepared Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using mysql functions but instead use mysqli 
however this is what you are looking for

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM links WHERE name LIKE '%$queried%' ";
foreach($keys as $k){
    $sql .= " OR name LIKE '%$k%' ";
}
$sql .= "LIMIT 0, 20";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```